# Access to two Back Cameras on iphone 15 with AVCaptureMultiCamSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I have an iPhone 12 Pro and I wrote code to access two cameras at same time. But it is only possible with the widecamera and frontcamera. Widecamera and ultrawide cameras at same time do not work. Do you know if it is possible with an iPhone 15 Pro? I use the functions with AVCaptureMultiCamSession.

I have tried it with AVCaptureMultiCamSession on iPhone 12 Pro.